# How can I overcome ValueError when converting string to integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer, python-3.6, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert a list of strings that are numbers into a list of integers. My goal is to go from this: ['3.14', '3.212', '3.248', '3.16'] to something like this: [3.14, 3.212, 3.248, 3.16].

I've tried using a for loop to convert each individual element of the list into an int using the basic int() function but I keep getting a ValueError

```py
pi_values = []
pi_vals = ['3.14', '3.212', '3.248', '3.16']

for k in pi_vals:
    j = int(k)
    pi_values.append(j)

print(pi_values)
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```py
[3.14, 3.212, 3.248, 3.16]
```

but this is the error I'm getting:

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.14'
```

How can I fix this issue? Most online sources I've consulted have directly suggested converting it using the int() function.

Comment: It's not `int`, it's `float`. So, use `j = float(k)`. I highly recommend you to read [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Typecast into float.

```
j = float(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` is only for numbers like -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,...
For fractions you need to use `float`:

```
pi_values = []
pi_vals = ['3.14', '3.212', '3.248', '3.16']

for k in pi_vals:
    j = float(k)
    pi_values.append(j)

print(pi_values)
```

Or in short:

```
pi_vals = ['3.14', '3.212', '3.248', '3.16']
[float(val) for val in pi_vals]
```

Output:

```
[3.14, 3.212, 3.248, 3.16]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Instead of `int` use `float`

```
pi_values = []
pi_vals = ['3.14', '3.212', '3.248', '3.16']

for k in pi_vals:
    j = float(k)
    pi_values.append(j)

print(pi_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float_strings = ['3.14', '2.4663']
floats = [float(number) for number in float_strings]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.